# I am having problems with the css highlighting text

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with the css side of the hypertext link, the strings that transport you to the other pages of the website, they are not highlighting when I hover over the message, when it comes to the stuff, I cannot see the problems with the code, could i have some help with this please?:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  hover: red;
}

a {
  color: white;
}


}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<u1>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Chocolate.html">Chocolate</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Mallow.html">Marshmallows</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Gummy.html">Gummy Candy</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Seasonal.html">Seasonal Candy</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Fizzy.html">Fizzy Candy</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Lollipops.html">Lollipops</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="Chewy.html">Chewy Candy</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="HardBoiled.html">Hard Boiled Candy</a></li><br>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="New.html">Newest Selection</a></li><br>
</u1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a typo, `u1` instead of `ul`
2. You have too many definitions of A so the hover is ignored, I removed `a { color: white; }`
3. Unnecessary inline list types on the LIs
4. Don't use float and br when not using float and br does the same. I removed `li { float: left; }` and `<br>`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


li a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}
li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="Chocolate.html">Chocolate</a></li>
  <li><a href="Mallow.html">Marshmallows</a></li>
  <li><a href="Gummy.html">Gummy Candy</a></li>
  <li><a href="Seasonal.html">Seasonal Candy</a></li>
  <li><a href="Fizzy.html">Fizzy Candy</a></li>
  <li><a href="Lollipops.html">Lollipops</a></li>
  <li><a href="Chewy.html">Chewy Candy</a></li>
  <li><a href="HardBoiled.html">Hard Boiled Candy</a></li>
  <li><a href="New.html">Newest Selection</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!